# print in python using python3 without python2 and python1 or both at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, spelling

I've tried `prynt(xd)` `prihnt(?O)` but none of them work:

```
prrrrrrint(xd)
prrrrrrint(xd)
prrrrrrint(xd)
prrrrrrint(xd)
prrrrrrint(xd)
prrrrrrint(xd)
```

Comment: `print("xd")`should work in any version of python.

Comment: Why are you using incorrect spellings of `print`?  Of course they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing:

I don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but I'm guessing that you want to know **how to print** in python, no?

Great, then here's how you do it:

In Python 3...

If you have a String, integer, float, etc. stored in variable `a`, then you can print by:

```
print(a)
```

For any version of Python under 3...

If you have a String, integer, float, etc. stored in variable `a`, then you can print by:

```
print a
```

Comment: As abarnert says to my answer how about python 0.9? :)

Comment: @U9-Forward Interesting question... I believe it's the same as Python 1 and 2. Don't trust me on this, though... :P

Comment: Yeah can copy the way i do it, :)

Comment: @U9-Forward Sure; thanks, by the way

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your question, but from the context I feel like you have some sort of confusion between `print` in python3.x and python2.x.

The difference between them is great because python broke backward compatibilty when migrating from python2 to python3.

So, the print command that you use in python2.x is actually a statement/keyword, like `x=1` we have `print a` which prints value of a. However in python3.x print was reduced to a function(method) like any other normal function you would've made.

Although you could also use same syntax of print in python2.x as in python3.x and it won't break.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In Python it's called `print`, correct spelling:

(should copy if don't remember)

```
print
```

Python version under 3:

```
print a
```

Python 3, do:

```
print(a)
```

As you see, even on stack-overflow it makes `print` a different color

Comment: Python 1 to 2, but no mention of 0.9? :)

Comment: @abarnert Wow, i never new there was a python 0.9

Comment: @abarnert Edited mine

Comment: See [Ancient Releases](https://www.python.org/download/releases/early/), [Older Source Releases](https://legacy.python.org/download/releases/src/), and [Releases](https://www.python.org/download/releases/). You can build and run most of them today on modern machines with a bit of work; 0.9 is actually the easiest until around 2.3.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks very much!!!, by the way should just directly install it will it interrupt my python 3.6

Comment: I wouldn’t install them onto anything on your PATH, especially not 0.9; I just keep them in their own directories and manually created aliases so `python1.0` sets a couple env variables and runs `~/oldpython/1.0.1/bin/python`. And even that’s probably overkill; the only real reason to run them is to see what the ancient days were like…

Comment: @abarnert I'll try to get it work...

Comment: @abarnert i can't seem to get it work...

Comment: At some point I’ll put together a blog post on everything I had to do to get most of them to work on macOS 10.13, maybe even with binaries. I only tried one or two of them on Windows and Linux, but I managed to build all but I think 2.0 on Mac.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks again, i am lucky that i can have all versions working because i am on Windows

Comment: @abarnert Wow the last page's link directs me to every version above 2.0

Comment: @abarnert Just ready to try again